# Help understanding Stein's proof of the Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm looking at the proof of the Cauchy integral formula given in Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis.

**Corollary 4.2** If $f$ is holomorphic in an open set $\Omega$, then $f$ has infinitely many complex derivatives in $\Omega.$ Moreover, if $C\subset \Omega$ is a circle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega$, then 
$$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta -z)^{n+1}} d\zeta$$ for all $z$ in the interior of $C$.

I don't understand the last paragraph in the below proof. Why does he say that because $z+h$ and $z$ stay at a finite distance from the boundary circle $C$, so the limit as $h$ tends to $-$, we have the final convergence? I think he's switching integral and the limit here, but to do that, don't we need uniform convergence? I'm not sure how this fact is exactly established. I would greatly appreciate any help to understand this completely.

[image]

Comment: but since $z$ and $z+h$ stays at a finite distance from the boundary of $C$ the convergence of the term in brackets is uniform when $h$ goes to $0$ because the denominators away from $0$.

Comment: @Basti Sorry I forgot to attach the proof. I kind of get what you mean but how can we explicitly show that for all $\zeta$ we can find a uniform $\delta$ for $h$?

Comment: The short answer is because the closed disk is compact. For fixed $h$, there is a $\delta_z$ that works for each $z$. The balls $B_{\delta_z}(z)$ are an open cover of the disk, so there is a finite subcover. i.e., a finite number of those balls that works. Take the smallest $\delta$ for that subcover and that is the uniform $delta$ you need.

Comment: Assume $C$ is the unit circle. The  $\int_C \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$ is an uniformly convergent integral for $|z| < r < 1$ and we can differentiate under the $\int$ sign without fear. Stein doesn't say anything more.